# Why is this PHP script working in one subdomain and not another identical one?

Tags: php, wordpress, csv

I have a php script that creates WordPress posts from a csv file ("file.csv") that is on the same subdomain as WordPress. This has been working for months, however, I just uploaded a new "file.csv" file to a couple of subdomains and the script is not working, resulting in a blank screen and does not create posts.

To troubleshoot, I checked other subdomains where I have the php script set up and uploaded the new "file.csv" file. It worked there.

So, on some subdomains the script is working and on some it is not. The WordPress installs are identical. The php script is identical, I downloaded and uploaded it from one domain to the other to troubleshoot. It works on one and not the other. I have tried identical "file.csv", still works on one subdomain and not the other.

The below error comes up in the error logs

> [17-Nov-2013 11:00:05] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 8388608 bytes) in /filepath/_adder.php on line 16

However the "file.csv" file is identical in both installs, and is the same size. But it still works in one and not the other.

Why might the script be working correctly on done subdomain and not the other? Any suggestions, things to try or tips would be very much appreciated.

For sake of completeness, below is the php script in question.

```
<?php
require_once('wp-config.php');

$siteurl = get_site_url();


function clearer($str) {
  //$str = iconv("UTF-8", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $str);
  $str = utf8_encode($str);
  $str = str_replace("’", "'", $str);
  $str = str_replace("–", "-", $str);
  return htmlspecialchars($str);
}

//file read
if(file_exists("file.csv")) $csv_lines  = file("file.csv");
if(is_array($csv_lines)) {

  $cnt = 15;
  for($i = 0; $i < $cnt; $i++) {
    $line = $csv_lines[$i];
    $line = trim($line);
    $first_char = true;
    $col_num = 0;
    $length = strlen($line);
    for($b = 0; $b < $length; $b++) {
      if($skip_char != true) {
        $process = true;
        if($first_char == true) {
          if($line[$b] == '"') {
            $terminator = '",';
            $process = false;
          }else
            $terminator = ',';
          $first_char = false;
        }

        if($line[$b] == '"'){
          $next_char = $line[$b + 1];
          if($next_char == '"')
            $skip_char = true;
          elseif($next_char == ',') {
            if($terminator == '",') {
              $first_char = true;
              $process = false;
              $skip_char = true;
            }
          }
        }

        if($process == true){
          if($line[$b] == ',') {
             if($terminator == ',') {
                $first_char = true;
                $process = false;
             }
          }
        }

        if($process == true)
          $column .= $line[$b];

        if($b == ($length - 1)) {
          $first_char = true;
        }

        if($first_char == true) {
          $values[$i][$col_num] = $column;
          $column = '';
          $col_num++;
        }
      }
      else
        $skip_char = false;
    }
  }

  $values = array_values($values);
  //print_r($values);

  /*************************************************/

  if(is_array($values)) {
    //file.csv read
    for($i = 0; $i < count($values); $i++) {
      unset($post);

      //check duplicate
      //$wpdb->show_errors();
      $wpdb->query("SELECT `ID` FROM `" . $wpdb->prefix . "posts`
                            WHERE `post_title` = '".clearer($values[$i][0])."' AND `post_status` = 'publish'");
        //echo $wpdb->num_rows;

      if($values[$i][0] != "Name" && $values[$i][0] != "" && $wpdb->num_rows == 0) {
        $post['name'] = clearer($values[$i][0]);
        $post['Address'] = clearer($values[$i][1]);
        $post['City'] = clearer($values[$i][2]);
        $post['Categories'] = $values[$i][3];
        $post['Tags'] = $values[$i][4];
        $post['Top_image'] = $values[$i][5];
        $post['Body_text'] = clearer($values[$i][6]);

        //details
        for($k = 7; $k <= 56; $k++) {
          $values[$i][$k] != '' ? $post['details'] .= "<em>".clearer($values[$i][$k])."</em>\r\n" : '';
        }

        //cats
        $categoryes = explode(";", $post['Categories']);
        foreach($categoryes AS $category_name) {
          $term = term_exists($category_name, 'category');
          if (is_array($term)) {
            //category exist
            $cats[] = $term['term_id'];
          }else{
            //add category
            wp_insert_term( $category_name, 'category' );
            $term = term_exists($category_name, 'category');
            $cats[] = $term['term_id'];
          }
        }

        //top image
        if($post['Top_image'] != "") {
          $im_name = md5($post['Top_image']).'.jpg';

          $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($post['Top_image']); 
          if ($im) {
            imagejpeg($im, ABSPATH.'images/'.$im_name);
            $post['topimage'] = '<img class="alignnone size-full" src="'.$siteurl.'/images/'.$im_name.'" alt="" />';
          }
        }

        //bottom images
        for($k = 57; $k <= 76; $k++) {
          if($values[$i][$k] != '') {
            $im_name = md5($values[$i][$k]).'.jpg';

            $im = @imagecreatefromjpeg($values[$i][$k]);
            if ($im) {
              imagejpeg($im, ABSPATH.'images/'.$im_name);
              $post['images'] .= '<a href="'.$siteurl.'/images/'.$im_name.'"><img class="alignnone size-full" 

src="'.$siteurl.'/images/'.$im_name.'" alt="" /></a>';
            }
          }
        }

        $post = array_map( 'stripslashes_deep', $post );

        //print_r($post);

        //post created
        $my_post = array (
           'post_title' => $post['name'],
           'post_content' => '
              <em>Address: '.$post['Address'].'</em>
              '.$post['topimage'].'
              '.$post['Body_text'].'
              <!--more-->
              '.$post['details'].'
              '.$post['images'].'
           ',
           'post_status' => 'publish',
           'post_author' => 1,
           'post_category' => $cats
        );
        unset($cats);

        //add post
        //echo "ID:" .
        $postid = wp_insert_post($my_post); //post ID

        //tags
        wp_set_post_tags( $postid, str_replace(';',',',$post['Tags']), true ); //tags

        echo $post['name']. ' - added. ';

        //google coords
        $address = preg_replace("!\((.*?)\)!si", " ", $post['Address']).', '.$post['City'];
        $json = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://hicon.by/temp/googlegeo.php?address='.urlencode($address)));
        //print_r($json);

        if($json->status == "OK") {
          //нашло адрес
          $google['status'] = $json->status;

          $params = $json->results[0]->address_components;
          if(is_array($params)) {
            foreach($params AS $id => $p) {
              if($p->types[0] == 'locality') $google['locality_name'] = $p->short_name;
              if($p->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_2') $google['sub_admin_code'] = $p->short_name;
              if($p->types[0] == 'administrative_area_level_1') $google['admin_code'] = $p->short_name;
              if($p->types[0] == 'country') $google['country_code'] = $p->short_name;
              if($p->types[0] == 'postal_code') $google['postal_code'] = $p->short_name;
            }
          }
          $google['address'] = $json->results[0]->formatted_address;
          $google['location']['lat'] = $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
          $google['location']['lng'] = $json->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

          //print_r($params);

          //print_r($google);

          //insert into DB
          $insert_code = $wpdb->insert( $wpdb->prefix . 'geo_mashup_locations',
                                        array( 'lat' => $google['location']['lat'], 'lng' => 

$google['location']['lng'], 'address' => $google['address'],
                                               'saved_name' => $post['name'], 'postal_code' => $google['postal_code'],
                                               'country_code' => $google['country_code'], 'admin_code' => 

$google['admin_code'],
                                               'sub_admin_code' => $google['sub_admin_code'], 'locality_name' => 

$google['locality_name'] ),
                                        array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )
                                      );
          if($insert_code) {
            $google_code_id = $wpdb->insert_id;
            $geo_date = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
            $wpdb->insert(
              $wpdb->prefix . 'geo_mashup_location_relationships',
              array( 'object_name' => 'post', 'object_id' => $postid, 'location_id' => $google_code_id, 'geo_date' => 

$geo_date ),
              array( '%s', '%s', '%s', '%s' )
            );
          }else{
            //can't insert data
          }

          echo ' address added.<br />';

        }else{
          //echo $json->status;
        }

      }
    } //$values end (for)
  }
}else{
  //not found file.csv
  echo 'not found file.csv';
}

$input = explode("\n", file_get_contents("file.csv"));
foreach ($input as $line) {
 // process all lines.
}

// This function removes first $CNT elements.
// More info:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php
$output = array_slice($input, $cnt);
file_put_contents("file.csv", implode("\n", $output));

?>
<html>
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
 CSV: <input name="file" type="file" />
 <input type="submit" value="Send File" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your "out of memory" error would seem to be fairly conclusive. Is this .csv file larger than previous? Have you checked the `memory_limit`s on these subdomains - when your script runs?

Comment: You're explaining the whole "subdomain" thing incorrectly, you meet to tell if all those subdomains are hosted on the same server, and how do you have your php set up.

but as @w3d explained, this is a memory limit issue. you need to have the same settings on all your hosts for the code to work properly.

Answer (score 2):

Your imported file is larger than limit allowed on the server. You are importing the large chuck of data and storing in Memory that is causing crashing. There are two ways to stop crashing.

1.You can put at the top of you code before any other thing written which give larger access to memory.

```
ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
```

2.You read the file line by line and process according to that.

My suggestion is to go for 2nd way and there are two reasons for suggestion.

1. As what will you do if the size increases beyond possible to keep the file memory. Either you have to split it or go for second option, so why don't you start with second options rather using at later stage.
2. Second Reason is Memory Allocation and Speed of Execution. If you adopt the second option the Memory will be less occupied and your program will execute faster than the reading full file in Memory then doing work on it.